# filter command in scapy is not working, I am running in windows

Tags: scapy, npcap

I wrote the below code in scapy for filtering UDP frames. But it was capturing all the frames just not only UDP.

```
sniff(filter = "UDP", timeout=5)

ERROR: Could not compile filter expression UDP
```

the output is:

```
- Sniffed: TCP:41 UDP:32 ICMP:0 Other:11
```

I'm using Windows 7. I already installed npcap-0.99-r9 and nmap-7.70. Can someone please suggest what could be the reason.

Comment: Have you tried with `udp` (lowercase) ?

Answer (score 2):

Hi,

The `filter` parameter is a [BPF filter](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.html): protocol names are lowercase.

You just need to use `sniff(filter="udp", timeout=5)`